# C# - split string

Tags: c#, string, split

I have some problems with split and check string.

I need to split string, replace halfs and check is this the same as the second string.

example: first string = tokyo second string = koyto

soo... S = a+b = b+a
S - a = b and S - b = a

a and b is part of one string (S) and may have different long in this case a = to and b = koy

first I need to check string length - is the are different - then write Error - it's easy

the I thought that I can compare strings in ASCII (case sensitivity is not important) and it' could be ok but... 
I can create string tooky which have got the same size in ASCII but is not created from split and invert parts of first string...

any ideas?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string S = "tokyo";
        string T = "kyoto";
           if (S.Length == T.Length)
           {
               split string ?
           }
        else
        Console.WriteLine("This two words are different. No result found.");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think you need to re-word this (and check your spelling) so that you have a well defined problem and a clear question about the problem you are having solving your problem. While I *think* I know what you are trying to do, your code is not doing any of that (and no use of any `split`).

Comment: I mean I see *lots* of problems... but have no idea what the OP is asking...  Problem 1?  `bool result` a local variable never used whatsoever, goes out of scope after `Console.Read()`... why?

Comment: I need to check if the string T can be create from string S by 
by one split and swap

Comment: Just look at the characters in the string, if they match, then you can create word T from word S.  But you are looking at bytes, then never comparing the contents of `GetBytes(S)`.  Then asking if S == T (which is never true in this case).  I don't think you are clear on what you *want to accomplish*.

Comment: Looking at the characters is not ok because I can create string tooky and it will be true but this istring wasn't create by split and swap

Comment: Well now I'm just confused.  What is the *objective* of this method in plain terms.  You can creates lots of different words with these 5 characters.

Comment: I think what he means is can you split string T into two substrings such that you can swap the two substrings and the result equals string S.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest doing the comparisons with strings. You can use the String.ToLower() method to convert them both to lowercase for comparison.

I am not exactly sure what problem you are trying to solve is, but from what I understand you are trying to check if string S can be split into two substrings that can be rearranged to make string T.

To check this you will want something similar to the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < S.length; i++) {
    string back = S.substring(i);
    string front = S.substring(0,i);
    if (T.equals(back + front))
         result = true;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not correct because tokyo and kytoo are not the same (build from split and swap)

Comment: I am confused with your statement. This code will set result to true if the words are "tokyo" and "kyoto", and will leave it as false if the words are "tokyo" and "kytoo", which is correct behavior to my knowledge

Comment: Maybe I'm too stupid for it but the name 'result' does not exist in current context and I wolud like to send Console.WriteLine message to user

Comment: Basically inside the if statement is where you want to inform the user. I put result = true simply as an indicator to show that when it reached that point you know that the two words comply to the rule

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare equality of two collections you should consider using LINQ:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string S = "tokyo";
        string T = "kyoto";
        if (S.Length == T.Length)
        {
            if (S.Intersect(T).Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Contents are the same");
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
        else
        Console.WriteLine("This two words are diferent. No result found.");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: there is no need for `ToCharArray`

Comment: @Selman22 whoops, forgot to remove those when I edited my code, edited and corrected.  Waste of memory ;)

Comment: This is not correct because tokyo and kytoo are not the same (build from split and swap)

Comment: I am confused with your statement. This code will set result to true if the words are "tokyo" and "kyoto", and will leave it as false if the words are "tokyo" and "kytoo", which is correct behavior to my knowledge